# Swift / C interop, struct data change in Swift not updating back in C

Tags: c, swift, pointers, struct

I have a C struct

```
struct Test {
  int a;
}

typedef struct Test Test;
```

and in C I create a pointer,

```
Test* myTestPointer = new Test();
```

I obtain the struct pointer `myTestPointer` in Swift, and I have checked the pointer does indeed point to the correct address in both Swift and C.

But I'm having some difficulty understanding why the following two pieces of code are not equivalent as measured by the value of `a` back in the C code?

```
let x = myTestPointer
x!.pointee.a = 123     // correctly changes the memory, as reflected back in C code
```

```
var x = myTestPointer!.pointee
x.a = 123  // does not reflect change back in C code
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment of the expression `myTestPointer!.pointee` (of type `Test)` to the variable `x` causes a copy of the struct.

The change to `x.a` effects this copy, but not the one pointed to by the pointer.

In actuality, struct copies are *really* often completely collided by the optimizer, but in this case, I think a copy always happens, because a pointer can act like a black box that enables any manner of external state observation/mutation.

In any case, you should not try to communicate differences in state back/forth between Swift and C (or frankly, between any two components of any software system) by mutation of shared state. Of course some times you need to, for performance reason, for building other communications primitives (e.g. building a message queue between processes, backed by an underlying shared memory region), but in general, this approach is begging for race conditions and weird synchronization difficulties.

Comment: I thought it must be something like that. Yes not ideal, but I need this for my game engine which has a C++ core, shared between iOS/Swift & Android/Kotlin (or any other C/C++ capable language). It's the only way I could see to write multi-platform games whilst maintaining excellent efficiency/speed. I may have a rethink though to see if there's a safer way to update data without writing lots of setter functions, rather than using my current approach of obtaining a struct and updating memory directly.

Comment: (Everything I'm about to say has huge caveats, as always measure and make tradeoffs as necessary) Usually game state/logic is fast enough that it's not the main bottle neck, as compared to the graphics rendering side of things. Indeed, there's lot of luxuries you might be able to afford yourself in terms of reactive streams (observers/publishers), notifications, etc. If you *did* want to take a mutated-shared-memory approach to updates, I would model that on the Swift side as functions on a struct which contains a pointer to your game state. Each fn would deref the pointer and edit in-place.

Comment: Yes I guess it's a case of weighing up the pros and cons. So long as I'm fastidious about memory management and how the render / UI thread work with my game data I should be okay. I did think It would have been nice to write a Swift version and a Kotlin version and a Whatever-else-version, but I have to draw the line somewhere. A change to one of those would mean I'd need to change all the others, so I went with the C/C++ route. I quite like the mutated-shared-memory approach but as Swift reminds me constantly I'm ultimately using Unsafe pointers.

Comment: @Pixel If you use a "gateway" object like the one I mentioned, the unsafe pointeriness gets hidden behinds its pleasant facade (`movePieceTo(x:y:)`, `castleQueenSide()`, etc.). You just need to ensure the reference memory outlives your little Swift facade over it.